# XML waypoints_index doesn’t match

Tags: optimization, routes

I’ve developed an application that sends points for routing. There’s an example of this application request below.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=-27.4497885,-53.9333278&destination=-27.4497885,-53.9333278&waypoints=optimize:true|-23.5106862,-46.5080633|-23.1575201,-47.0048426|-23.496135,-46.2939104|-23.5392269,-46.2879977|-23.2752377,-45.9399387|-22.8683161,-48.4575258|-22.6956944,-47.669097|-22.4301754,-46.8227837|-23.6118844,-46.5765539|-20.0398784,-47.7478325&sensor=false&key=xxxxxxx
The xml file answer gives me the routed directions and the order of each point in the request was routed (named as waypoint index).
Well, the directions routed and the waypoint index doesn’t match.
Can anyone help me?